# Рядовой научный сотрудник

Tags: стилистика

Насколько правильно выражение "рядовой научный сотрудник"? Ведь научный сотрудник уже не рядовой? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Кажется, это вопрос контекста. Если бы по улице шли одни научные сотрудники, то каждый среди их числа ничем бы не был отличен от другого. Также надо определиться с этим свойством: связано оно именно с этой научной областью или же с этим сотрудником.

Comment: Именно с научной областью.

Comment: Тогда, полагаю, вопрос сводится к контексту. Да и разве не может человек не выделяться из своей области, если в ней он не один?

Comment: Может, я имел в виду по сравнению с теми сотрудниками, у кого нет ученой степени.

Comment: Это самое "может" и должно быть отражено в контексте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Младший научный сотрудник", "старший научный сотрудник" -- это ведь из штатного расписания, такие записи делают в трудовой книжке. Человек, занимающий такого рода должность, может быть совершенно заурядным, не хватающим звёзд с неба, т.е. действительно "рядовым научным сотрудником".

Answer (score 3):

Рядовой НС = обычный, заурядный НС. И не только НС.

Рядовой - обычный, находящийся **в ряду** себе подобных, ничем особенно не выделяющийся. Так что "рядовым"  в обычно понимании может быть хоть директор, хоть маршал, хоть сам Президент.

К воинскому званию прямого отношения не иемет.

> РЯДОВОЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. Ничем не выделяющийся, обычный. Р. случай. Р-ая
>   работа, операция. 2. Не принадлежащий к командному и начальствующему
>   составу, к руководству. Р. состав. Р-ое звание. Р. боец. Р. колхозник.
>   Р-ая сотрудница почты. Р. работник бухгалтерии. 3...

(БТС)

Answer (score 0):

> > Ведь научный сотрудник уже не рядовой?

Не рядовой – это ученый. "Рядовой ученый" и впрямь не звучит. А научный сотрудник, как правило, вполне рядовой. В крайнем случае сержант.

Comment: *"Рядовой ученый" и впрямь не звучит.* Еще как звучит. Сразу видно, что вы в той кухне никогда не варились. ))) Впрочем это не важно. Читайте словарь  - и не пишите глупостёв. ***1. Ничем не  выделяющийся, обычный. Р. случай. Р-ая работа, операция***

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/11332)

Comment: Любезный @behemothus, не путайте рядовой случай с "рядовым ученым". *Сразу видно, что вы в той кухне никогда не варились.* Не хотите ли сказать, что вы и есть тот самый ученый?

Comment: Я не вступаю с Вами в дискуссию не по теме.

Comment: *Я рядовой ученый. Я допускаю, что быть скульптором – это призвание. Но как вы его обнаружили? Как это можно родиться поэтом, живописцем,* (Андрей Битов)

Comment: *Но этимъ правомъ могутъ неоспоримо пользоваться только Дарвины. Обыкновенный, рядовой ученый, къ сожалѣнію, вынужденъ добывать это право съ бою; отъ него читающая публика можетъ требовать знаменія его правоты, доказательства несостоятельности его противника* (Тимирязев)

Comment: На мой взгляд behemothus пишет вам совершенно правильные вещи. В любой профессии 80% заурядных представителей (рядовых), но встречаются и весьма незаурядные, их намного меньше.

Comment: Давайте тогда писать и "рядовой чемпион". Наверняка можно надыбать пару примеров из литературы или газет.

Comment: @Niemand Аналогия некорректна. Вы почему-то полагаете, что ученые -- это какая-то редкая профессия. Чемпионов в России около сотни, ну может тысяча. А научных сотрудников -- десятки тысяч, сотни тысяч. И да, когда чемпионов будут в вузах штамповать в год десятками тысяч -- вполне корректно будет сказать 'я самый обычный, рядовой чемпион'. А вот продавцы - уже рядовая профессия. Рядовой космонавт - пока еще нонсенс.

Comment: @Niemand *Давайте тогда писать и "рядовой чемпион"* - Если вы у меня спрашиваете, то не вижу причин сопротивляться... Среди десятков тысяч чемпионов, могут быть, скажем,две-три сотни многократных чемпионов, остальные - рядовые. Всё зависит только от контекста. Во всяком случае первому (по Кузнецову)   значению  не противоречит.

Comment: @АК *Аналогия некорректна. Вы почему-то полагаете, что ученые* - Вы правы по сути, но аналогия-то как раз корректна.)) **РЯДОВОЙ, 1. Ничем не выделяющийся, обычный. Р. случай. Р-ая работа, операция.** - почему бы не быть "рядовому" чемпиону?!

Comment: Дорогой @behemothus, если упереться рогом, то конечно, всё может быть.

Comment: @Niemand *если упереться рогом* - это ваши проблемы. Я подобное не коментирую.